# How to solve ORA-54019: Virtual column expression cannot be changed because it is a partitioning column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that is partitioned by a virtual column and I want to change the behaviour of that virtual column, but apparently this is not possible to do the way I tried it.

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE
MODIFY VIRTUAL_COLUMN 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_DATE(SUBSTR(SOME_COLUMN, 4, 8), 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

How can I change that virtual column?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.  Also, your format string has 10 characters, but your `substr()` is only returning 8.

Comment: dropping the table? no, I did not try, but I would not like to drop the table.

Comment: . . You are using that "virtual" column to define the storage for the table.  If you want that logic, add a *new* column.  Alternatively, you pretty much have to recreate the table, because changing the definition will require repartitioning it.

Answer (score 1):

If the virtual column forms part of the partitioning key, you can't change its definition.

If you want to change this so that you can also change the partition scheme, you'll need to:

- Add a new virtual column with the expression you want
- Change the partitioning scheme to use the new virtual column

If you're on 18c or higher, you can do this with `alter table`:

```
create table t (
  c1 date,
  v1 number as (
    to_number ( to_char ( c1, 'yyyymmdd' ) )
  )
) partition by range ( v1 ) (
  partition p0 values less than ( 20200101 )
);

alter table t
  modify v1 number as (
    to_number ( to_char ( c1, 'yyyymm' ) )
  );

ORA-54019: Virtual column expression cannot be changed because it is a partitioning column
  
alter table t
  add v2 number as (
    to_number ( to_char ( c1, 'yyyymm' ) )
  );
  
alter table t
  modify partition by range ( v2 ) (
    partition p0 values less than ( 202001 )
  ) online;

select column_name 
from   user_part_key_columns
where  name = 'T';

COLUMN_NAME   
V2
```

For older releases, you'll want to use [DBMS_redefinition](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/online-table-redefinition-enhancements-11gr1) to minimize any downtime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, I use 12c so I can not test this. Hopefully, it will help others.